# Advanced home network setup to secure dev. Kubernetes cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes, virtual-machine, firewall, esxi

I'm about to configure a VM host that's running Kubernetes for my development purposes. I've a limited budget, so I try my best to keep power consumption to a minimum, thus the virtualization in the first place. I know that it's not recommended to use a virtualized firewall at the perimeter, but this is for home use and I guess vmware esxi is secure enough today, that breaking out of a VM is nearly if not possible at all. What do you guys think? Any suggestions?

Thanks in regard!

Virtualized network setup:
[image]

Comment: So, what specifically is your question?

Comment: I'm just curious if there are others with a similar setup. Perhaps I'm doing something very wrong here, thus getting pointers from you experts on how I can improve my design would be of great value.